# Using jQuery UI modal dialog as confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a way i can use a jQuery UI based modal dialog for confirmation instead of the normal JS confirm()? I would like to be able to do something like:

```
if (jquery_ui_confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    // do something
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated because you need to provide the HTML for the dialog box and handle the result as callbacks, but yeah there's no reason this can't work. Have you tried it?

Comment: ... Its part of the basic docs; http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: you can also use Jquery Alert plugin as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var jqConfirm = function(msg, success) {
    var dialogObj = $("<div style='display:none'>"+msg+"</div>");
    $("body").append(dialogObj);
    $(dialogObj).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "OK": function() {
         success();
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

Call this function using

```
jqConfirm("This will delete all records", function(){ /*do something here */});
```

Comment: I would also clean up the DOM and remove the newly created dialog by adding $(this).remove() after you close the dialog. If you confirm and cancel a dozen times, there will be a dozen DIV tags added to the DOM.

Comment: (body).append(dialogObj); should be ("body").append(dialogObj);

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.. you can provide requried html to dialog

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirmation Dialog">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"
            style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Would you like to delete this item?
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Jquery Alert plugin as well. Here is a link: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/